# Self-signed SSL certificate on chromebook (and android)

Tags: tls, certificates, chrome

I am having the following problem on both my android phone and on my chromebook. I'm running a website on an internal server (10.3.3.3) using nginx with a self-signed ssl certificate. Since it is just an internal server, I put the CN=10.3.3.3. All of our desktop machines work just fine (they give a warning about the certificate, but after we tell the browser to connect anyways, it works just fine). This is true of all browsers I've tried on the desktop machines (**chrome**, firefox, safari).

The problem is on my android phone and chromebook. On both of these, when I type in the ip address, I get the typical chrome yellow screen saying there is something wrong with the certificate. When I click "proceed anyways", it looks like it is trying to load, but the site never comes up. What do I need to do to get chrome on these mobile devices to work?

P.S. I did import the certificate into Chrome on the chromebook and it shows up under "Authorities".

As an interesting test, I downloaded a [ChromiumOS virtual machine](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net) and it works just fine (gives cert error, but when I click proceed, everything works fine). I should have noted that the chromebook and the android phone are coming in over VPN, but everything else on the VPN works fine (ssh to the web server, etc).

**The Certificate**

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 9485437517293169565 (0x83a30b2a7d6c2b9d)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=XX, ST=XX, L=XXXX, O=XXXXXX
        Validity
            Not Before: Apr  2 12:41:40 2014 GMT
            Not After : Apr  1 12:41:40 2016 GMT
        Subject: C=XX, ST=XX, L=XXXX, O=XXXXXX
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    XXXXXXXXXX
                Exponent: XXXXX
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Key Usage: 
                Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment, Certificate Sign
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                IP Address:10.3.3.3
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem had nothing to do with the certificate and everything to do with the fact that the client was coming in over the VPN. When the client was physically on the network, everything worked fine.

I ended up having to change the MTU on the ubuntu server and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

- the common name cannot be an IP address. You may put IP addresses into the subject alternative name section, but as IP address not DNS
- the certificate might need a CA=true property if you want to import it as authority, simply self-signing might not be enough. You might still be able to import it and it will show up, but does not work.
- it failed for me for Firefox and Chrome until I've put also extended key usage of "TLS Web Server Authentication" in the certificate and also Netscape Cert Type 'server', which seems to be missing from your certificate. After I've added both it also works with Chrome on Android.

This is the certificate which works for me:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 1893982163 (0x70e3dfd3)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN=foo.com
        Validity
            Not Before: Apr  7 18:47:17 2014 GMT
            Not After : Apr  7 18:47:17 2015 GMT
        Subject: CN=foo.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus: ...
                 Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                32:04:C3:BF:60:46:D4:4A:90:2F:CC:55:F1:B1:7D:B7:BF:7A:61:4B
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:                    keyid:32:04:C3:BF:60:46:D4:4A:90:2F:CC:55:F1:B1:7D:B7:BF:7A:61:4B

            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                DirName:
                serial:70:E3:DF:D3

            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                IP Address:192.168.178.4
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Certificate Sign
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication
            Netscape Cert Type: 
                SSL Server
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        ....
```

Comment: After I posted this I tried putting the IP in the subject alternative name (have had CA=true the whole time) and it still didn't work.

Comment: It's hard to tell more without seeing the certificate.

Comment: I added details on the cert. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks to me that it is not a certificate issue. Can you check by accessing the website on android and chromebook after disabling SSL on the server or using a plain HTTP link? That will tell us if its due to the certificate or not.

Comment: @mikeazo: see edited response. You probably need to add extended key usage of "TLS Web Server Authentication".

Comment: @mikeazo see edit: Netscape Cert Type server seems to be also required.

Comment: @xkcd, it appears you may be (at least partially) correct. I had setup the server to enforce https only (redirect if they try regular http connection). I switched this back and I can connect over HTTP on my desktop, but cannot connect over HTTP (through VPN) on the mobile devices. This is strange as I see the GET request from the mobile device in access.log (and nothing in error.log).

Comment: @xkcd I took a packet capture on the server and it responds to the GET request (over HTTP). I see the typical 3-way handshake, then the GET request, followed by the expected response packets. Then a bunch of retransmissions. Perhaps it is a firewall issue (but SSH and VNC to machines on the internal network over the VPN work just fine).

Comment: @mikeazo - Yes, I would suspect the firewall too. Looks more and more to be a networking issue then a certificate or security issue. I suggest that you investigate from that angle and when it starts working with plain HTTP requests then shift to SSL/TLS. Good luck.

Comment: @xkcd still I can't figure out why it works on desktop over VPN but not the mobile devices over VPN. I'll see what I can figure out

Comment: @mikeazo - Depends on the differences in VPN softwares and their settings. See if you can find the difference between the desktop VPN and android VPN, that will be the key to the solution.

Comment: @xkcd wanted to update you (and thanks to you and Steffen for your help). I created a very simple test site (http only), connected to VPN then loaded up site. It worked just fine. So, there must be something with the site I am trying to use that is having issues. I'm trying to use OwnCloud on nginx. I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: @xkcd, it ended up being an MTU issue. I lowered the MTU on the server from 1500 to 1300 and everything works fine now.

Comment: @mikeazo - Congrats, I'm glad it worked out for you so fast ... cz these network issues are a pain in the ass to solve.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I'll give you the bounty as I sent you chasing down a rabbit hole. Sorry about that.